# How to timeout a call in asyncio for Python

Tags: python, observable, python-asyncio

I see a function like this in one of the python packages, some calls take too long and I want it to timeout. How do I add a timeout here?

```
async def run(self, obs: Observable):
    await obs\
        .map(self.parse)\
        .map(self.run_service)\
        .run_until_complete()

def run_service(self):
    w = RunWorker()
    result = w.process()
```

Comment: There is no way to stop a task unless it has provided a way to do so.  What would you do instead?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to break the calls triggered by the `map`method you use there (of which we have no clue, as you don't put any code neither say from which library you get these "Observable" objects).

Anyway, you have to unfold the calls made by these "map" calls in an explicit `for` or `async for` construct, and add in the body of this `for` an explict check for timeout: a plain `if` statement which would raise a Timeout error or return with an error code.

The exact way to replace your `map` calls, and if it gives you the granularity you need, depends on the nature of your project.

Otherwise, to keep the opaque `map` calls, to arrange for your `run` function to be executed as a task, and create a separate co-routine to check for the timeout, cancelling the  `run` task when it expires.

[I will try to get a proof of concept for that]

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

`async def run(self, obs: Observable):
    await obs\
        .map(self.parse)\
        .map(self.run_service)\
        .run_until_complete()

async def run_with_timeout(self, args):
 return await asyncio.wait_for(self.run_service(args), TIME_OUT) 
`